# File Open Help - Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to scripting and thus have come here to ask for some assistance to help me build an excel macro. I am currently working on an excel file to speed up data capture and verification. I cannot get around on how to go get the actual data.

I currently have a drive which contains all folder and excel files:

`Y:\Audit\Accounting_Data\XXXXX_Company_Names\07 Jul 2013\XXXXX.xls`

First problem for me is that each company sends a file in a different file naming convention. Some have all dates in numeric values while others have alpha numeric data (and not in same order, i.e some are DD/MM/YYYY while others have MMMM/DD/YYYY). I cannot modify the file naming conventions as they are shared to other services as well and  most important is that I have only read access to these files.

Second problem is that each company do not produce files on the same day. Some produce audit files everyday and some only on weekdays (the ones for the weekend are then created and sent to me on monday morning) >> i was thinking about using object.fso to get the last 10 files by their date.created criteria and have excel stop searching when it does not find any more files // problem like mentionned before is that some files are created on the same date.

Also I was trying to implement a loop function (with a stop when it hits a blank cell) as companies can be added or removed from the list defined in the sheet1.

What i would like is a way to have excel go to the current month folder and open the 10 previous excel files and copy paste data of specific cells in the current worksheet.

This is what I have come up with at the moment :

Cells A4:A12=File Paths (i.e. Y:\Audit\Accounting_Data\XXXXX_Company_Names)

```
var1=file path
var2=month (numeric)
var3=month
var4=year

Range (a4:a50)    
Do Loop till blank cell in Range (a4:a50)
 If cell is not blank then
  goto "var1\var2+var3+var4\"

  Excel is now in Y:\Audit\Accounting_Data\XXXXX_Company_Names\07 Jul 2013\ (hopefully)
```

How do I tell excel to open the previous 10 excel files relative to today's date and stop if less or none found

```
 Copy Data 
 Paste Data

 Move to next line
   Repeat the Open 10 previous files / Copy / Paste

else when cell is blank

 stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you. It should go through each folder in an array and get all the files stored in the folder, sort them by date, open up to 10 files and copy each one onto a worksheet.

In This example I used "Sheet1" as the worksheet to copy all the data to and I used a sheet named "DateList" to store all of the file paths and created dates on.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim DirList() As Variant
    Dim Path As Variant
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim dt As Date
    Dim CurrFile As String
    Dim RowOffset As Long

    DirList = Array("C:\Test\", "C:\Test - Copy\")          'Create list of folders to search
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    'Create file system object
    Sheets("DateList").Cells.Delete
    Sheets("DateList").Range("A1").Value = "Path"
    Sheets("DateLIst").Range("B1").Value = "Date Created"

    'Loop through every directory in the list
    For Each Path In DirList()
        CurrFile = Dir(Path)

        'For each file in the current directory
        Do While CurrFile <> ""
            'Get the files date created
            dt = fso.GetFile(Path & CurrFile).DateCreated

            'Add the file data to a "DateList"
            Sheets("DateList").Cells(Sheets("DateList").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = Path & CurrFile
            Sheets("DateList").Cells(Sheets("DateList").UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2).Value = Format(dt, "yyyymmdd")

            CurrFile = Dir
        Loop

        Sheets("DateList").Select
        'Sort Files
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DateList").Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), _
                            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                            Order:=xlDescending, _
                            DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange Sheets("DateList").UsedRange
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        'Get up to 10 files
        For i = 2 To 11
            If Sheets("DateList").Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
                Exit For
            End If

            'Open the file, copy it to the bottom of the data on Sheet1
            '***NOTE*** THIS ASSUMES SHEET1 STARTS OFF BLANK
            Workbooks.Open Sheets("DateList").Cells(i, 1).Value
            ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1 + RowOffset, 1)
            RowOffset = RowOffset + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Next

        Sheets("DateList").Select
        Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2)).Delete
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Ripster. The code provided did not exactly worked the way I was hoping it to but it gave me the direction. I am testing the new code as of now and will post it when done. Thanks for the tip.